# Alternate method for finding ways of distribution

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

> Find the number of ways in which $n$ distinct balls can be distributed between $n$ children such that exactly one child doesn't get a ball.

This can be solved easily by looking at it as division and distribution.

Here, $n-2$ children get exactly $1$ ball, one child gets $2$ balls and one child gets no ball. The number of possible divisions is just

$$\frac{n!}{0!2!(1!)^{n-2}(n-2)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}$$

Hence the number of possible distributions is

$$\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}\times n!=^nC_2\times n!$$

This answer looks suspiciously close to the answers we would get by using the normal selection and permutation method. However I couldn't figure out any "normal" way. Can you help me out?

Comment: What is your question?   Should say:  Usually in these problems the balls are meant to be indistinguishable.  If you want them to be distinct, you should say so explicitly.

Comment: My bad, I have edited the question. My teacher hinted me that there is another way to solve this without using the aforementioned method. I couldn't find any other method

Comment: Well, if the balls are identical then your answer is clearly too big.  All you need to do is to choose the kid who gets nothing ($n$ choices) then choose the kid who gets two ($n-1$ choices) and that's it.  So $n(n-1)$.

Comment: So...now the balls are back to being distinct?  It's hard to keep up with your edits.  But in that case, just pick the kid who gets none ($n$), then pick the kid who gets two ($n-1$) then given the latter kid two ($\binom n2$) and give all the others one ($(n-2)!$).  So the answer is $n\times (n-1)\times \binom n2\times (n-2)!$ which matches what you got.

Comment: @lulu I was in a hurry while editing. Thank you for the answer, I have understood it.

Answer (score 1):

Make $n$ piles with $0,2, 1,1,1...$  balls with the pile of $2$ chosen in $\binom n 2$ ways, and the piles permuted in $n!$  ways giving $\binom n 2 n!$ arrangements

Line up the kids in (say) alphabetical order and distribute.